# .net DateTimePicker space between date parts

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datetimepicker, visual-studio-2017

I have an odd problem. I have a space between date parts. I tried with short format or custom format, the results are like you can see bellow.

Does anyone had such a problem? I drag a new DateTimePicker on the windows form, and looks the same. I'm working with .net 4.0 with Visual Studio 2017. I compiled the solutions with Visual Studio 2012 and I get the same result.

I appreciate any sugestion.

[image: DateTimePicker looks odd]

Comment: The problem is only on my computer. I have Win10 Pro x64, Creators update.

Comment: It was a problem with Windows. After an update, the issue was fixed.